# What is the full definition of this symbol in the Universal Coefficient Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

[image]

This symbol hasn't been defined in Rotman's Algebraic Topology, can someone give me a full definition of what it means?

Comment: Take the usual chain complex for computing homology, tensor it with $G$, and then take the homology of the resulting chain complex.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So $H_n(X;G) = H_n(C_*(X) \otimes G)?$

Comment: I find it *very* hard to believe that a textbook proves universal coefficients theorem without first defining homology w. coefficients.

Comment: In fact, the relevant section ('Universal Coefficients') of Rotman's book [starts with the definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWUoW.jpg)

Comment: The definition from Rotman's book defines "a pair of spaces".  The book doesn't explicitly define what the symbol $H_n(X;G)$ means, so I'm asking what it means here.

Comment: $H_n(X,\emptyset;G)$